# Team city cant find namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2015, teamcity

I have a project in VS2015 and within my main project I have a reference to the AjaxcontrolToolKit. I have Copy Local set to true. Within VS the solution builds without issue.

In Team city I receive the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AjaxControlToolkit' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, even though I could see the reference in the VS project references, the code built and the `using` statement was fine in code. Before Team City picked the reference up, in VS I had to install the toolkit via the nuget package manager console.